# return an anonymous function to a jsonp call without a callback

Tags: javascript, jsonp

So, I was asked to create some kind of web service that return a javascript library (that changes based on the query params) to a jsonp call.
I tried to write down some scripts to do so and looks like it's possible and easy.
Now the question is, I read a lot of articles about jsonp but, why should I not make something like this? And what could I do to achive the same result but not this way?

client sample here:

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = '//my_url/testjsonp.php';

document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
```

server sample here:

```
echo 'var a = function(){ /* basically what i want here */ }()';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of issues with that:

1. You're creating a global `a` variable. The page calling your service should be in charge of that, so unless you've made the `a` configurable, that's a problem.
2. The code within your function would have to magically know what it was supposed to do with the data. That's contrary to the point of JSONP, which is for the server just to return the data and let the client decide what to do with it.

Those two reasons are why a standard JSONP request allows the caller to specify the callback name (usually with a `callback` parameter, but the name varies)

```
http://example.com/path/to/service?callback=foo
```

...and a standard JSONP response looks like this:

```
foo({/*...JSON here...*/});
```

That way, the caller defines the function, which knows what to do with the data you're passing into it.

Comment: for the a variable it's configurable via query param of course, for the other part I can see what the point is, in my case the server magically know what to do with the data so it's ok but thanks a lot for the reply, very informative!

Comment: @gamera_the_beast: #2 is basically a matter of avoiding tight coupling. Perhaps in your specific situation the server knows what to do with it, but now that endpoint is page-specific. Whereas if the server just returns data, without any assumptions about the structure of the page, then the page can be developed and maintained independently -- element IDs and classes updated, things moved around, etc. The only time the server code would have to change would be if the page needed new/different data.

Comment: good point, my case is pretty weird so the endpoint is not coupled with a single page but with all the pages that need that endpoint (for now at least) but I understand. +1